# Using so on in sentences to avoid repeating a word

Tags: word-usage, expressions, expression-choice

I would like to explain something without repeating words. I try to do that using _so_on. However, I do not know whether this is acceptable in English or not?

For example,

The first drawer is used to store the files of the first class while the second drawer is used to store the files of the second class.

I try to avoid repeating words, so I did this:

The first drawer is used store the files of the first class and so on of the second drawer.

I am not sure if my sentence is understandable or not? I feel it changes the meaning of the first sentences.

Any help, please?

Comment: If you're using *so on* to indicate a pattern, then you should establish it first imho - so it could be _first class' files are in first drawer, second class' files in second drawer, and so on_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so on OR so forth is used to show continuity with the pattern.

"First row is reserved for semester-1 students, 2nd row is for semester-2, so on and so forth"

I think the right way is this -

"The first drawer is used to store the files of the first class, second drawer for the 2nd class so on and so forth."

"**so on**" is the less formal way of "**so forth**"